# Changing derivative to difference quotient

Tags: differentiation, notation, approximations, calculus, models

Can differential be changed to Delta or difference? In high school education, in the acceleration section of Newton's formula 2, acceleration is a change velocity (velocity difference) divided by a change in time (time difference) which is also symbolized as the total differential of speed with respect to time.

[image: newton law]

Then, in college, I didn't see that kind of thing anymore. If I take the example of thermodynamics in the heat generation of cables with the following formula, so I can immediately enter the final and initial values. Is that true?

[image: heat generation cable]

Answer (score 1):

The difference and the derivative is the same thing, but in the limit that the difference becomes "very small". So here is what I like you to do:

1. Draw the function $s = s(t) = t^3$.
2. Ask yourself, what is the change of at the time $t=2s$?

One way to answer this is to take differences, e.g. by taking the points $(t_1, s_1) = (1.5, 1.5^3)$ and
$(t_2, s_2) = (2.5, 2.5^3)$. This yields as value $\Delta s/\Delta t = 12.25$, which is shown as red line in the following plot.

[image: t^3]

The chosen interval around the target value $t=2$ are arbitrary. Hence, I could have chosen to use the points
$(t_1, s_1) = (1.8, 1.8^3)$ and
$(t_2, s_2) = (2.2, 2.2^3)$, which yields $\Delta s/\Delta t = 12.04$, or I could have chosen a non-symmetric interval around $t=2$.
So the natural thing to ask is how we could improve this result of differences? And also, how can we obtain a result which is independent of the chosen interval? One possible answer to this question is that we can take smaller and smaller intervals. This leads to limit $\Delta t \to 0$ and hence to the derivative.

Answer (score 0):

If one has a relation like $$F = m \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t},$$ but $F$ is not necessarily constant, it is properly converted to a difference by integration (i.e. using the fundamental theorem of calculus):

$$\int_{t_1}^{t_2} F{\left(t\right)} \, \mathrm{d} t = m\int_{t_1}^{t_2} \frac{\mathrm{d}v}{\mathrm{d}t} \, \mathrm{d}t = m \Delta v.$$

As said in the comments, the left-hand side will only become $F \Delta t$ if $F{\left(t\right)}$ is constant.

So without focusing too much on the details of your other example too much (I am not sure if , it comes down to whether the temperature changes enough for the resistance to noticeably change, the current depends on time or not, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can as long as $\Delta T$ and $\Delta t$ are small enough.

What is "small enough"?  First decide how much of an error in $I^2R$ that you can tolerate.  Then try your discretized version with trial values for $\Delta T$ and $\Delta t$.   Then try with those original values divided by two.  If the two resulting values of $I^2R$ differ by less than your tolerance, then you are good to go (or stop).  If the difference is greater than your tolerance, repeat starting with the $\Delta T/2$ and $\Delta t/2$.  Continue in this way until you satisfy your tolerance condition.